# Align ImageView to top right of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I've a imageView in my layout which serves as a background which doesn't scale. But I need to have my image in the topright corner of the screen. I now have my image in the top left corner of the screen. This is my xml for the imageview:

```
    <ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:src="@drawable/achtergrond"
android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

I also tried to put it in a linearlayout which has gravity="top|right" but that doesn't remove the white space around the picture because it's with the match_parent sizes. I also need to keep the scale of the picture, so I can't do fill_parent.

I hope someone can help me with this!

Comment: Shouldn't you set width and height to `wrap_content`? Maybe RelativeLayout is what your looking for to align the ImageView to the top right corner.

Comment: post the key parts(attributes) of parent layout

Answer (score 25):

Maybe add

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

to your `ImageView`? I had a similar problem.

Answer (score 15):

The following layout will position your image (or any other view) at the top right corner of the screen. Check comments below code block for more details.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The important parts are the wrapping `RelativeLayout` and the `layout_alignParentRight`and `layout_alignParentTop`set to true on the view itself.

This won't wrap your complete view yet since it's all `wrap_content`. You can [use different size resources per screen type](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) or work with different `layout_width` and `layout_height` and then use the `scaleType` property as you whish (probably `fitXY` to scale image to match the view).

Don't use a `LinearLayout` if not necessary. [Documentation on `RelativeLayout`can be found here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).

Answer (score 0):

with linearlayout to fit the imageview with the image use

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: If I would do that the image would get a different scale so I can't use it.

Comment: you can adjust using padding

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that hcpl's answer is right although I wasn't being able to achieve that because I had set gravity of the RelativeLayout to Center so it was centralizing every child view to center. So if you who came here having the same issue please, pay attention to the parent view.